# How to Disconnect/Connect from Broadband connection from TELNET?

Tags: networking, router

```
CAdecoder       dd              igmpproxy       ping6           tcci
ConfigFilter    delgroup        inadyn          portbindcmd     tce
EmappS          deluser         inetd           ppp_monitor     tcwdog
\[              dhcp6c          init            pppcmd          test
ac              dhcp6s          insmod          pppd            tftp
acl             dhcpdetector    ip              pppoe-relay     tftpd
addgroup        dhcrelay        ip6tables       pppstat         top
adduser         dirname         ipcs            ps              tr069
adslcmd         dmesg           iptables        ptmcmd          tr69
adslstat        dnsmasq         iwpriv          pwd             traceroute
algcmd          dropbear        kill            qoscmd          traceroute6
arp             ebtables        killall         radvd           true
ash             echo            klogd           reboot          udhcpc
ated            ecmh            ln              ripd            udhcpd
atmcmd          email4log       login           rm              umount
autoFwUpgrade   env             ls              rmdir           uname
awk             ethcmd          lsmod           rmmod           uptime
basename        expr            maceui          route           usleep
bftpd           ez-ipupdate     mailsend        rt2860apd       utelnetd
boa             false           md5             run-parts       vah
br2684ctl       firewallcmd     mdev            sed             vahcmd
brasinfo        free            mkdir           sh              vconfig
brctl           freeMemory      more            sleep           w
busybox         ftpget          mount           smuxctl         wan
cat             ftpput          mtd             snmpd           wc
cfg_manager     ftpset          mtr             sys             wget
chmod           getty           mv              syscmd          wlan
cp              grep            netstat         sysctl          wlancmd
cpu             head            nslookup        sysdiagd        wscd
crond           hostname        ntpclient       syslogd         yes
cut             hw_nat          passwd          taskset         zebra
cwmpcmd         ifconfig        pidof           tc
date            igmp            ping            tcapi
```

Got all those commands on my Zyxel router, is there a way to disconnect/connect from broadband connection without reboot the router? The purpose of this is get a fresh IP address by using telnet. btw my connection uses Dynamic IP.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can issue a disconnect command, but even if you do, it's not a guarantee you will get a new IP address.  How you do that likely would be ipconfig, info provided, isn't enough to answer this question

Comment: what else do you need? i want to know what are the commands for disconnect/connect me from my broadband without using the "reboot" command, in my case is guaranteed because my ISP gives me a new IP everyime i restart my pc or turn on/off my router.

Comment: What does each command do?  It's not even guaranteed there is a command to issue a reboot.

Comment: well i thought you were well knowledge on this..seems you asking me now instead :) ps: theres a "reboot" cmd listed if you didnt notice it and yes performs reboot but thats not what im asking for here

Comment: If you give a manual that describes the command I can answer the question.  Your image isn't searchable....I already suggested ipconfig should be a possible solution, but without knowing how it works, its not possible to answer.  Your job to provide us the documentation on the commands

Answer (score 0):

Different manufacturers may have different ways to configure PPPoE on Linux. So I can't give you the exact solution.

Please check if the man command exists on your router. If yes, please try to run man adslcmd or man pppcmd to check if these two commands has the option to start and stop the PPPoE connection.

If man is not available, you may try -h or /? parameter on these two commands(adslcmd -h or adslcmd /?) to check if there is any help information showing up.

If it still doesn't work, as Ramhound has mentioned above, you may try to use ifconfig to disable and re-enable the interface or try to restart the network services.

Hope this helps.